# iOS: Synchronizing access to CoreData

Tags: ios, multithreading, core-data, magicalrecord

I'm new to CoreData and I'm trying to create a simple application.

Assume I have a function:

```
func saveEntry(entry: Entry) {
   let moc = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType)
   moc.parentContext = savingContext

  moc.pefrormBlockAndWait { 
    // find if MOC has entry
    // if not => create
    // else => update
    // saving logic here
  }
}
```

It can introduce a problem: if I call `saveEntry` from two threads, passing the same entry it will duplicate it. So I've added serial queue to my DB adapter and doing in following manner:

```
func saveEntry(entry: Entry) {
    dispatch_sync(serialDbQueue) { // (1)
        let moc = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType)
        moc.parentContext = savingContext

        moc.pefrormBlockAndWait {  // (2)
            // find if MOC has entry
            // if not => create
            // else => update
            // saving logic here
        }
    }
}
```

And it works fine, until I'd like to add another interface function:

```
func saveEntries(entries: [Entry]) {
    dispatch_sync(serialDbQueue) {  // (3)
        let moc = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType)
        moc.parentContext = savingContext

        moc.pefrormBlockAndWait { 
            entries.forEach { saveEntry($0) }
        }
    }
}
```

And now I have deadlock: 1 will be called on serialDbQueue and wait till saving finishes. 2 will be called on private queue and will wait for 3. And 3 is waiting for 1.

So what is correct way to handle synchronizing access? As far as I understand it's not safe to keep one MOC and perform saves on it because of reasons described here: http://saulmora.com/coredata/magicalrecord/2013/09/15/why-contextforcurrentthread-doesn-t-work-in-magicalrecord.html

Comment: Are you sure that serial queue is necessary? Why does enqueuing two operations via `performBlockAndWait` cause a problem for you if you perform your upset check within that block?

Comment: @Jonah yes, I am. If I run everything with a signle MOC - it's ok. But as you can see `saveEntry` creates a MOC for each invocation. So you'll have parallel operations

Comment: Oops, I should have read carefully. Rather than a serial queue to create many mocs why not share a moc which will then act as that queue?

Comment: Are you sure it is safe? I saw MagicalRecord creates new context for each save

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try to implement this with a single `NSManagedObjectContext` as the control mechanism. Each context maintains a serial operation queue so multiple threads can call `performBlock:` or `performBlockAndWait:` without any danger of concurrent access (though you must be cautious of the context's data changing between the time the block is enqueued and when it eventually executes). As long as all work within the context is being done on the correct queue (via `performBlock`) there's no inherent danger in enqueuing work from multiple threads.

There are of course some complications to consider and I can't offer real suggestions without knowing much more about your app.

- What object will be responsible for creating this context and how will it be made available to every object which needs it?
- With a shared context it becomes difficult to know when work on that context is "finished" (it's operation queue is empty) if that represents a meaningful state in your app.
- With a shared context it is more difficult to abandon changes should you you want to discard unsaved modifications in the event of an error (you'll need to actually revert those changes rather than simply discard the context without saving).

Comment: Thank you very much! I have a DB signleton, that contains all save-read related logic. I guess it will create a private context and perform all changes on it. Are you sure it's safe to maintain signle context and perform all changes on it (despite the fact that Saul Mora mentioned)?

Comment: @user1284151 Saul is addressing a real but unrelated concern. Core Data originally relied on `NSConfinementConcurrencyType` per-thread confinement of `NSManagedObjectContext`s but there are limits to how well thread based concurrency can be optimized. The preferred pattern, now adopted by MagicalRecord, is to use queue confinement which does not necessarily couple a context to a single thread. MagicalRecord's `contextForCurrentThread` is therefore no longer useful or valid. Under either model sharing a context is valid within it's confinement bounds.